# Could not find the OffLine WLST class

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle ATS 12.5.0.3. on Windows 2008 R2 server.
At the end of the installation I get a warrning, that some actions failed. After looking into a log, I found:

> Configuring data sources...  D:\OracleATS\bin..\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe
>   -Djava.library.path=D:\OracleATS\bin..\install\lib -jar dbsetup.jar -setdefaultds  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the OffLine WLST class      at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.getOfflineWLSTScriptPathInternal(WLSTUtil.java:128)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOfflineInternal(WLSTUtil.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOffline(WLSTUtil.java:298)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtilWrapper.setupOffline(WLSTUtilWrapper.java:29)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.(WLSTInterpreter.java:212)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.(WLSTInterpreter.java:121)
>     at
>   oracle.oats.tools.databaseconfig.utils.DataSourceInitializer.(DataSourceInitializer.java:49)
>     at oracle.oats.tools.databaseconfig.ui.dbSetup.main(dbSetup.java:83)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLST_offline  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)   at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.getOfflineWLSTScriptPathInternal(WLSTUtil.java:121)
>     ... 7 more ERROR: Unknown error (code: 1)

After some research, I tried to set CLASSPATH system variable to "." (it was not set at all previously). But it made no difference...

I am out of ideas how to fix this. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue today, installing OATS 13.1.0.1. Basically, it fails at the step of installing FMW (fusion middleware). It seems to fail because its installation step checks a lock file which was already created by the setup.bat.

Steps to correct this issue:

1. Uninstall clean. If uninstall/bin/uninstall.bat did not work, stop Oracle ATS services and delete them using regedit
2. Install FMW first. You can find fmw jar file from fmw folder in your unpacked OATS installation package directory (your fmw jar file name may vary). This step requires cmd run as administrator and the java should be from your jdk location
   `java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_infrastructure.jar`
   To make this jive with the next step, you can choose C:\OracleATS\wls (or [the directory of your choice for OATS installation]\wls) for Oracle Home.
3. If you have failed the installation step before, it might have created the OLT schema in your local database. To avoid this issue, use your favorite SQL client to run these commands
   `drop user oats cascade; drop user olt cascade; drop user otm cascade;`
4. Now run setup.bat to install OATS, use custom, unselect fusion middleware before continuing on installation

Once installation is finished, you can check it by visiting http://localhost:8088/admin/LoginSubmit.do and login using administrator:[password you set during installation]

Answer (score 0):

i am not able to find the class, 
com.oracle.cie.domain.script....

so i have done the following,

I have used all jars in wlserver\server\lib in classpath now the issue is resolved.

and added -Dweblogic.home= -Dbea.home=

now i have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Weblogic 12.1.4, it was a matter of missing:

```
-Dbea.home=%BEA_HOME%
```